how can I build my angular app like local in production
I have an angular app that uses docxtemplater which uses pizzip and this works on my local build because of angular.js and typescript setting but it fails on prod.  I tried everything and changed different build settings but none worked.  Is there a way to build like local on production?
This is just for a special case.  I need to build the prod like local right now because I need to get this working for a demo.
thanks
this is what my tsconfig.json looks like.  I have tried these config changes
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
        "es2020",
        "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "os:": [
            "src/empty.ts"
        ]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
}

}
this is my angular.js
 "production": {
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "25mb",
                                "maximumError": "30mb"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                "maximumWarning": "75kb",
                                "maximumError": "90kb"
                            }
                        ],
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputHashing": "all", 
                        "buildOptimizer": false,
                        "optimization": false
                    }


You should set "aot : false " in angular.json file and make build. Because the prod build use aot compiler.

@MudassarMustafai tried it but didn't work either

Just change the property default configuration to development, then when you run npm run build it will run the dev build
     "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },


tried it but it still doesn't work.

@wil then building like local is not the problem, since that is what you did, move the codebase to server and run ng serve instead!
